# Format hard drives w/o live CD

Tags: boot, grub2

Someone gave me their laptop, and it has Ububtu on it.
I have to reformat the hard dive.
How can I do this without the Ubuntu disks?

Comment: do you mean to format the whole partitions present in it or different partition which has another OS

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear, can you provide a little more detail as to what specifically you are trying to do?  We can all provide better guidance with more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes to other partitions. But you can not make changes to your Ubuntu partition while running Ubuntu. You need a live cd/USB and boot from them and then you can make changes to your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: thank you I am downloading this os to a flash drive and hoping that will work

Comment: Download it to Ubuntu you are running and use Unetbootin software to create Ubuntu live USB. Also copy the downloaded iso to the same flash drive. create a folder in flash drive and copy ubuntu iso into that it won't give problems when installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wipe your current setup and redo it you format your disc with the installation media of the operating system you want to install on to the system.

Since you will need an installation disc to install an operating system that is the easiest method.

Comment: Thank you but that does not work I tried using the install disk,  If I remember correctly it does not recognise the format so it will not delete the partion

Comment: @CHILLI sorry can not be true. When formatting the current format does not matter. If you install windows it does not care it is ext and will even -force- you to format it to ntfs before you can install. Same for Linux: if ntfs you will be forced to format to ext or another supported filesystem

Answer (score 0):

'Gparted' has its own [Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). It is less and simpler than the OS Live but does the trick.